# Is GLWidget for OpenTK and GTK# reliable?

Tags: c#, opengl, gtk#, opentk

I'm creating an application that need a nice GUI and some openGL rendering (I need to draw 3D objects based on mouse click coordinates). Since I need this to be multiplataform I'm using mono and OpenTK, for the GUI I was thinking GTK#, and I stumbled upon GLWidget http://www.opentk.com/project/glwidget, but I added this to my project, created a simple window, with a VBox, in one division I added a menu bar and in the other the GLWidget, and now the project won't compile, it gives this error:
Error: The compiler appears to have crashed. Check the build output pad for details. (GLGTK)
I did add the reference to GLWidget.dll
Am I missing something or does this GLWidget just not work? Oh, by the way, I'm using Monodevelop, in case it matters.

Comment: Make sure you're also referencing OpenTK. OpenTK.dll should be copied to the output directory.

Comment: Ok, I got it to compile, now I think the problem is, I don't know how to use it, and OpenTK's documentation doesn't help much. Does anyone know of a good tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into it a lot, and yes, it's a great tool once you get all the start up process out of the way, which is no walk in the park given that there's next to zero documentation.